# pg_dump error input/output error backup cannot complete

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I keep on getting this error when backing up my database using pgAdmin III

```
pg_dump: [archiver] could not write to output file: input/output error
pg_dump: *** aborted because of error
```

I still have space on my file system. I'm backing up using PLAIN and none of the below options are checked:

- `--oids`
- `--inserts`
- `--disable-dollar-quoting`
- `--data-only`
- `-n (dump all schemas)`
- `--no-owner`
- `--create`
- `--clean`

What could be the problem?

Comment: "could not write to output file", what file and do you have write permissions?

Comment: Disk or file system error? What's the OS? File system type? Storage type? anything in the system error logs?